# выбрать имена всех таблиц, созданных назначенным пользователем базы данных

Tags: sql, sql-server

Итак, я есть пользователь-админ Lnk, хочу выбрать имена таблиц, созданных мной. Я пишу запрос:

```sql
select * from sys.database_principals
```

и в нем среди значений столбца name нет меня, то есть нет Lnk.
Далее, сделав запрос

```sql
select * from sys.database_principals
```

я вижу, что для всех таблиц, которые я создал в некоторой базе, в principal_id стоит null (короче говоря, 0). Из предыдущего запроса узнаю, что principal_id = 0 соответствует name = 'public'. Но почему public, ведь это вообще роль, а не пользователь? Пользователь - Lnk, в данный момент я сижу под ним, базу данных я создавал тоже будучи им, так почему, когда я пишу

```sql
select * from sys.objects
where type = 'U'
and
principal_id = (select principal_id from sys.database_principals where name = user_name())
```

мне вообще ничего не выводит? Получается, что этот пользователь вообще ничего не создал? но ведь это не так. Где ошибка и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос основан на нескольких неверных постулатах.

1. В принципе, если не вести специального логирования, невозможно определить кем создан объект в БД. Эта информация не сохраняется.

Столбец principal_id - это вообще не о создателе: [sys.objects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> ID of the individual owner, if **different** from the schema owner.
>
> ID персонального владельца, если **отличается** от владельца схемы.

2. Логин и пользователь БД - это не одно и то же. Вы выбираете пользователей БД из `sys.database_principals`, но, судя по всему, логин Lnk является членом роли sysadmin и поэтому имеет доступ ко всем БД, а в конкретных базах как пользователь не создан.